# Calling values from an array in the string.xml file in an Android app

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have built a fortune cook app that previously currently has values hardcoded into an array

#### FortuneActivity.java

```
package juangallardo.emofortunecookie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class FortuneActivity extends Activity {

  private FortuneBox mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fortune);

    // Declare our View variables and assign them the Views from the layout file
    final TextView fortuneLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fortuneTextView);
    Button showFortuneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFortuneButton);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          String fortune = mFortuneBox.getFortune();
          // Update the label with dynamic fortune
          fortuneLabel.setText(fortune);
      }
    };
    showFortuneButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

  }
}
```

#### FortuneBox.java

```
package juangallardo.emofortunecookie;

import java.util.Random;

public class FortuneBox {

  public String[] mFortunes = {

        "What is the point?",
        "Sometimes it is best to just sleep in.",
  #98 other fortunes...
};

// Methods (abilities)
public String getFortune() {

    String fortune = "";

    // Randomly select a fortune
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFortunes.length);

    fortune = mFortunes[randomNumber];

    return fortune;
  }
}
```

---

The problem is that now I want to add a Spanish version. So I realize that i should add that array into the `strings.xml`.

I looked up string resources on the [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). and it gave me the idea to add this to my code

#### strings.xml

```
<string-array name="emo_fortunes">
    <item>What is the point?</item>
    <item>Sometimes it is best to just sleep in.</item>
</string-array>
```

But now I am stuck on where to add this part that has the part about Resources, etc.

[image]

I followed along to a tutorial from Treehouse about strings but my app kept crashing.

Basically the change that I made was to make the original array into

#### FortuneBox.java

```
# above unchanged from previous code
public String[] mFortunes;
# below unchanged from previous code
```

#### FortuneActivity.java

```
# same imports as before
public class FortuneActivity extends Activity {

private FortuneBox mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fortune);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    final String[] mFortuneBox = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);

    // Declare our View variables and assign them the Views from the layout file
    final TextView fortuneLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fortuneTextView);
    Button showFortuneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFortuneButton);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String fortune = mFortuneBox.getFortune();
            // Update the label with dynamic fortune
            fortuneLabel.setText(fortune);
        }
    };
    showFortuneButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

  }
}
```

These were my errors, but not sure where to go from here as I am new to Android and I have not touched Java since college.

#### log

[image]

#### FortuneActivity.java

[image]

#### FortuneBox.java

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikki has the right answer, but it is a little confusing. In your code above, you are using the same name for two different variables: `mFortuneBox`. This is the root of your trouble:

```
private FortuneBox mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox();
...
final String[] mFortuneBox = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);
```

Change the second one to a different name, like this, and the errors go away:

```
final String[] fortunes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);
```

However, you still aren't using these fortunes from the array anywhere. You can actually delete `fortunes` from your Activity and move it to your FortuneBox class instead. This is slightly tricky, though, as you need to know what the `context` is to get a string array resource in your other class. The `context` is the Activity, so you need to pass this along as a parameter when you create your FortuneBox object.

I'd recommend a slight restructuring. Below are the two files that should work for you:

**FortuneActivity.java**

```
public class FortuneActivity extends Activity {

    private FortuneBox mFortuneBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fortune);

        mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox(this);

        // Declare our View variables and assign them the Views from the layout file
        final TextView fortuneLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fortuneTextView);
        Button showFortuneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFortuneButton);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String fortune = mFortuneBox.getFortune();
                // Update the label with dynamic fortune
                fortuneLabel.setText(fortune);
            }
        };
        showFortuneButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }
}
```

**FortuneBox.java**

```
public class FortuneBox {

    public String[] mFortunes;

    public FortuneBox(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        mFortunes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);
    }

    // Methods (abilities)
    public String getFortune() {

        String fortune = "";

        // Randomly select a fortune
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFortunes.length);

        fortune = mFortunes[randomNumber];

        return fortune;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation on why that was not working. It works fine now with the English, now off to add the spanish.

Comment: Awesome - glad you're past it!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple. You can not access a non-final from an inner class (in this case your OnClickListener).

```
final String[] mFortuneBox = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);
```

Try just changing the line to look like this one above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have more problems?

Comment: Now I only have the error that is in the updated picture. that `Cannot find symbol method for getFortune()`

Comment: *getFortune()* is a method from **FortuneBox** class. Now, if you get the *mFortuneBox[]* in your *Activity.onCreate()* ... can't you just do: *Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFortunes.length);
    fortuneLabel.setText(mFortunes[randomNumber]);* inside your OnClickListener?

Comment: Unless you init the values inside FortuneBox, you're gonna get null values.

Comment: That actually caused more errors but I think the problem is not too big because errors show that I just have to rename `getFortunes` or intitialize it or? I will keep searching to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The mFortuneBox variable in the previous way you have used is an object of FortuneBox class and hence this call *mFortuneBox.getFortune()* works.
In the later changed code, you have made mFortuneBox variable a reference to an Array of strings.  But still tried calling mFortuneBox.getFortune(). 'getFortune()' is a method of FortuneBox class right, so you can call it with an object of Forune Box class itself.

Try doing this:
final String[] fortuneArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.emo_fortunes);
and
private FortuneBox mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox();
Now call mFortuneBox.getFortune(fortunearray) sending it this array to the getfortune method.
Now let the getFortune() method randomly pick one from this array passed and return the random string picked

Comment: I did the first change, and the second part of your answer seems to be already existing? Not sure if I put the `mFortuneBox.getFortune(fortunearray)` in the correct location. can you tell me what line that is supposed to replace or be added to?

Comment: Save the output or resources onto *String[] fortuneArray* and the declare mFortuneBox as "FortuneBox mFortuneBox = new FortuneBox();

Comment: Sorry but those instructions lost me. I did what you said and though I now have no errors. Now the app crashes when I push the button to get a new fortune. If it's not too much trouble, would you be so kind as to list where what line replaces what line because I may have changed the wrong things. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Mikki, yes I had updated the code above under "Update 2"

Comment: @JGallardo: The fortunebox class seems to not initialize array 'mFortunes' but still access it.
-->In FortuneActivity class :
String fortune = mFortuneBox.getFortune();==>String fortune=mFortuneBox.getFortune(fortuneArray);
-->In FortuneBox class:
public String getFortune() {--- ---} change this to below
public String getFortune(String[] mFortune){---  ----}
please check.